# Using jsf.ajax.request from Javascript to do AJAX calls in JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf

Some background: I have two 'h:dataTable' elements in my .xhtml page. When the users right click on a cell in the first datatable, the page shows a context menu. Selecting a particular menu item from this context menu should ideally update the contents of the other datatable.

To implement this, I created a javascript function in JQuery that uses jsf.ajax.request() to send an AJAX request to my backing bean. This call looks like the following:

```
jsf.ajax.request($eventCell, null, {execute: 'selectedRowId selectedColumnId',
                                    render: bugsTable,
                                    assignBugMode : "1",
                                    reportsToCompare : $('input[id$="reportsToCompare"]').val(),
                                    cellRowId: $.trim($rowId),
                                    cellColumnId: $.trim($columnId)
                                    });
```

Here, "bugsTable" is the id of the second h:dataTable element that needs to be updated after the AJAX call returns. "selectedRowId" and "selectedColumnId" are 'h:inputText' elements on the .xhtml page that I need to process on the server side in order to calculate the correct values to be shown in bugsTable.

What I am observing is: when I send the AJAX request to the server, the execute portion of JSF lifecycle gets executed correctly, but the "bugsTable" element does not get updated. In firebug, I could see that the AJAX request resulted into following response from the server:

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">2177233720285299449:-1589577009450482760</update>
</changes>
<extension primefacesCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":false}</extension>
</partial-response>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use JSF ajax tag?

Comment: I think you can only use `jsf.ajax.request` this way if the first argument points to component implementing `ClientBahaviorHolder` or there is a similar limitation.

Comment: Yes, I think mrembisz is right. I was able to get this working using <f:ajax> tag.