# How to implement JQuery confirm dialog with JSF 

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to use JQuery dialog when I press a button into JSF page in order to confirm action execution(in my case to confirm the deletion of rows).
I found this JQuery code working perfectly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                // Accordion
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

                // Tabs
                $('#tabs').tabs();


                // Dialog           
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 600,
                    buttons: {
                        "Ok": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        }, 
                        "Cancel": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        } 
                    }
                });

                // Dialog Link
                $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                // Datepicker
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    inline: true
                });

                // Slider
                $('#slider').slider({
                    range: true,
                    values: [17, 67]
                });

                // Progressbar
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: 20 
                });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*demo page css*/
            body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
            .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
            #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
            #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
            ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
            ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Dialog NOTE: Dialog is not generated by UI in this demo so it can be visually styled in themeroller-->
        <h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>
        <p><a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a></p>

        <!-- ui-dialog -->
        <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
            <p>Dialog Test</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I need to call the dialog from this button into Java Server Faces page:

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{bean.deleteid}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

Would you help me please to implement this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an approach that I use

You need two buttons

first one will be hidden and will be called as a result of clicking `Yes` in the confirm dialog, this hidden button will be the one that will call the server side method and will do the `render` using the `f:ajax`

```
<h:commandButton id="myHiddenButtonID" value="DeleteHiddenButton" action="#{bean.deleteid}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="@form" ></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

now to the button that will open the dialog, this button will also submit the form to the server with `execute="@form"` (in case you have selection column for example)

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="openDialogFunc()"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

now to the implementation of the js function

```
function openDialogFunc(data){
    if (data.status === 'success') {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             width: 600,
             buttons: {
                 "Ok": function() { 
                     $("#myHiddenButtonID").click();
                     $(this).dialog("close"); 
                 }, 
                 "Cancel": function() { 
                     $(this).dialog("close"); 
                 } 
             }
         });
    }
}
```

Notice that only upon clicking the OK dialog button there will be an execution of your hidden button `$("#myHiddenButtonID").click();` otherwise nothing will happen...

But I really strongly recommend you to use `h:head` instead of `head` and `<h:panelGroup` instead of div ... look at my previous example... [jQuery Dialog in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439565/617373)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you sure that there is no other possible solution directly to call the ajax without using the hidden button?

Comment: INMO you really better do it this way, the other option is to write some js code that will simulate the same thing that the `f:ajax` do... I haven't seen "imitations of f:ajax with js more than once or twice" so the hidden button is the Best and Safe solution...

Comment: I'm just interested how this can be implemented. Would you show me a quick code snippet?

Comment: google for jsf.ajax.request https://www.google.com/search?q=jsf.ajax.request&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a , but looking at the following related issues (cause of trying to use it) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912735/using-jsf-ajax-request-from-javascript-to-do-ajax-calls-in-jsf-2-0 you can look at the comments that recommend to use f:ajax ...

Answer (score 3):

If you have to call it say on click of commandbutton then use `onclick` event

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{bean.deleteid}" onclick="return myjavascriptmethod">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

then in the dialog you can check the condition for confirmation, on click of Okay dispatch the event.

Edit As per comment:

when you dont want to use a div, I just used a panel Grid, you can do something like this:

xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelGridAsDialogTest" style="display:none;">
        <h:outputLabel value="I Am a dialog test" />
    </h:panelGrid>
var alreadyValidated = false;
function testJQueryDialog(buttonReference){
    if(!alreadyValidated) {                
    $('#panelGridAsDialogTest').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function(event) { 
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    alreadyValidated = true;
                    jQuery(buttonReference).trigger("click");
                }, 
                "Cancel": function(event) { 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                } 
           }
       });
    }
    return alreadyValidated;
}
```

If you want to stick to div but make your code work you can just use the same javascript given above, and replace the id with div id.

Comment: I added the `onclick` attribute and it works. But no matter what I click the button code is executed. How I have to edit the code in order to stop exaction?

Comment: On click of "No" in your dialog add event.preventDefault() that will resolve your issue

Comment: so in your case your cancel code will look like this :        "Cancel": function(event) { 
                            $(this).dialog("close");  event.preventDefault();                         
                        } 
                    }

Comment: It's not working. Right after I press the button the row is deleted. The dialog is not preventing the deletion of the row.

Comment: However there is one more important problem that I want to ask: How I can remove this div `<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display:none">
    <p>Dialog Test</p>
</div>` and pass the content of the dialog via the `onclick="return myjavascriptmethod"`? Now if I remove the div the dialog will not work.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler approach would be to not use a jquery dailog for confirmation message, just use normal javascript confirm box in the **onclick**, no need to reinvent the wheel:

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{bean.deleteid}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

You must add **return** otherwise jsf will ignore what the user chose from the confirmation box, so if the user say clicks cancel the delete function will still be executed.