# JSF f:ajax prompt before any action

Tags: ajax, jsf

How I can show dialog before any f:ajax action.
I have code as following:

```
    <h:commandButton  value="Create Project" styleClass="greyishBtn submitForm" action="#{projectController.delete}">
          <f:ajax execute="@form"  onevent="function(data) {createProjectEventHandler(data);}" render=":tblProject txtNewProjectName txtNewProjectStartDate taNewProjectDesc"/>
    </h:commandButton>
```

This code works fine, but I need a confirm dialog before call delete action, I tried onevent, but it only have begin, success and complete events, what I need is confirm dialog before 'begin' event.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the ajax even starts you can cancel it (ajax) or the submit action itself by using `onclick="return false"` in the `<h:commandButton` itself...

So the simplest way it to use js `confirm("Delete?")` dialog with `onclick`

```
<h:commandButton  onclick="return confirm('Delete?');" value="Create Project" styleClass="greyishBtn submitForm" action="#{projectController.delete}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form"  onevent="function(data) {createProjectEventHandler(data);}" render=":tblProject txtNewProjectName txtNewProjectStartDate taNewProjectDesc"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

---

A more advanced way could be found here [jQuery UI confirm dialog not returns true/false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418713/617373) it uses jQuery dialog with JSF