# Calling a backing bean method from within jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, dialog, backing-beans

Im working on a JSF file where I have a javascript function, and some jquery involved
in this.
I have designed a dialog with two button: 1) Ok and 2) Cancel.
I have designed it in such a way that the Cancel button will abort the process, 
and there is no problem with that.
But, what I want to accomplish is that when the user presses Ok then the program
should call a backing bean(java bean) method, 
Have anyone of you been able to manage this?

Thankful for all your help & tip

Comment: take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/11418713/617373 might help ya

Answer (score 2):

To the point, you need to let jQuery trigger the click event on the HTML representation of a JSF `<h:commandButton>`. You could if necessary hide the form/button with CSS `display:none`.

E.g.

```
<h:form id="formId" style="display:none">
    ...
    <h:commandButton id="buttonId" ... />
</h:form>
```

with

```
$("[id='formId:buttonId']").click();
```

This is however somewhat clumsy. Why not just using the `<h:commandButton>` directly as "OK" button? Further, reinventing jQuery based components for JSF may in long term be a pain. Have you looked at for example [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) to save yourself the headache and boilerplate code? It is using jQuery and jQuery UI under the covers already. See also e.g. [`<p:confirmDialog>` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf).

#### See also:

- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved from CSS, HTML, JavaScript, jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery/)

Comment: Sorry for this, I forgot to mention that what I want to achieve is to make the "OK" button to connect to the JSF action attribute within the commandbutton I have. Preferably without the need to use ajax...

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need this :

```
<h:form>
   <h:commandButton value="OK" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include richfaces, you can use rich jsFunction component to call action method of you backing bean
you can see http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jsFunction.jsf;jsessionid=168EE2D49DC8BB1BA781B1C880B4B511?c=jsFunction&tab=usage

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="pressOK" reRender="showname" action="#{bean.action}" oncomplete="callback()">

    </a4j:jsFunction>
```

with this, you can call javascript function pressOK()