# call a method after the execution of the filtering of primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces

I have this datatable:

```
<p:dataTable  id="tabla_gral" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.verTabla}" var="item"  paginator="true" rows="15" rowKey="#{item.no}" value="#{consumoMaterial.listadoConsumo}" filteredValue="#{consumoMaterial.listadoConsumoFiltered}">  
                        <p:ajax event="filter"  listener="#{consumoMaterial.actualizarSaldos}" update=":form2:tabla_gral"/>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Búsqueda de Consumo por: #{consumoMaterial.tipoBuscar}: '#{consumoMaterial.codigo}'"/>
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column exportable="#{consumoMaterial.no}" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.no}" id="cclave" sortBy="#{item.no}" filterBy="#{item.no}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Nro"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.no}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column exportable="#{consumoMaterial.centroCosto}" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.centroCosto}" id="cconcepto" sortBy="#{item.centroCosto}" filterBy="#{item.centroCosto}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Centro de Costo"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.centroCosto}"/>            
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column exportable="#{consumoMaterial.codigoAlmacen}" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.codigoAlmacen}" id="ctipo" sortBy="#{item.codigoAlmacen}" filterBy="#{item.codigoAlmacen}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Almacén"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.codigoAlmacen}"/>
                        </p:column> </p:dataTable>
```

I want to call a method after the execution of the filtering of primefaces datatable, 
I tested with

```
 <p:ajax event="filter"  listener="#{consumoMaterial.actualizarSaldos}" update=":form2:tabla_gral"/>
```

but when call actualizarSaldos listadoConsumoFiltered is null.

Comment: You need to show bean code and attribute you used for <p:column>.

Comment: ok, i will edit now the question...

Comment: I tested with Primefaces 3.4.1 and that work, you should show bean code !

Comment: @RongNK I want to call my method after filter not while fielter... understand??

Comment: oh, sorry for my english, you can.

Comment: Notice: <p:ajax event="filter" have attribute "oncomplete"

and you can follow BalusC in his post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800088/calling-a-backing-bean-method-from-within-jquery