# JSF & Javascript - Displaying a confirmation box for a form only when validation is passed

Tags: jquery, jsf-1.2

I need to display a JQuery confirm box for a form, but I only want the form to display once the form is successfully validated from the Faces Life Cycle. I am using JSF1.2 (legacy project which needs a minor validation tweak).

I used this post: [How to implement JQuery confirm dialog with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656664/how-to-implement-jquery-confirm-dialog-with-jsf)  but i believe this will only work with JSF 2 onwards?

Anyone know how to achieve this in JSF1.2?

Appreciate any help

Many thanks

Comment: Are you basically asking how to conditionally render a HTML `<script>` element when the current faces request is a postback and the validation has not failed? I.e. `rendered="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}"`? Or are you asking how to do the jQuery confirm box thing within that conditionally rendered `<script>`? But this has in turn got completely nothing to do with JSF versions.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks for the comment. I'm just wanting a JQuery/JS dialog box which says "Are you sure you want to submit this?" once the form is validated successfully.  User then chooses Yes or No and it gets submitted or doesn't.  (As an addition, I only want to show the dialog box if a certain value if in one of the form fields, but I am OK with figuring that part out)

Comment: JSF doesn't care about *which* JS code exactly you're going to execute. Just conditionally render that `<script>` as instructed in the previous comment.